# No se visualiza css en otro archivo con apache y centos

Tags: css, apache, centos6

Tengo un archivo bastante simple, cuyo CSS se ejecuta sin problemas en Ubuntu y Windows:

**Archivo HTML: probando.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PROBANDO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Principal</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Y su respectiva hoja de estilos:

**ARCHIVO CSS: styles.css**

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-family: arial;
    color: gray;
} 

h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el mismo archivo .html en Centos 6, con Apache 2.2, el CSS simplemente NO SE EJECUTA. Pero si incluyo el CSS dentro de una etiqueta en el HEAD del archivo .html, y elimino la referencia al archivo externo (href="styles.css") entonces no tengo problema, y todo se visualiza como se espera.

Utilizando las herramientas de Google Chrome, el mensaje de error es:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

Por supuesto, esta no es una situación normal. He intentado agregando

AddType text/css css

al archivo de configuración de Apache, reiniciando, etc., pero sigue sin funcionar el CSS cuando lo invoco desde otro archivo. También cambié la ruta agregando un "/" antes del nombre del archivo, inclusive colocando la ruta absoluta al mismo desde el servidor (`href="https://dominio-ejemplo.net/styles.css"`), pero tampoco he podido resolver el caso.

Todos los permisos están asignados al usuario Apache, y en 755 el acceso respectivo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Dijiste que probaste el archivo en Ubunto y Windows, ¿qué versión de Apache tienen esos 2 servidores?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a cambiar en tu html la parte de `rel="stylesheet"`, de forma que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
<link type="text/css" href="ruta-al-css">
```

En caso de que no te funcione, prueba mirando esta [página](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see), hay varias respuestas, alguna podría ser la solución.

Comment: agradezco tu respuesta pero ya he tratado con eso, y visto previamente el enlace que envías, realizado todas las pruebas del caso, y sigue sin funcionar